# send entity model in postman

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, postman

I create a web API and want to check it with postman but don't know how to post my entity model.always model is null

I use [FromForm] send me model but all value is null and when use [Frombody]
send null

Comment: What is a `tblProvince`?

Comment: Are you really intending to post a form with a field value being json? This looks like you should be making the userId a path/query param and posting raw json for the tblProvince.

Comment: you need to send a json object with the same properties as your model

Answer (score 12, accepted):

.`your error is the CONTENT TYPE you're using to send the request` .. you choose `x-www-form-url-encoded` (the format for the HTML FORMS) ..  `BUT if you want to use WebAPI and send your Entity in the PAYLOAD of yours request via REST .. you have to set CONTENT - TYPE as application/JSON` ..

so `in POSTMAN do:`

1- choose type `RAW`

2- choose on the dropdown that appears `application/json`

3- `paste your JSON in the Text Area`

4- `send it`

Hope it helps you!!

Comment: that work for me
but how to send to userid param?
i send this {"Title":"test","Polygon":"test","IsActive":"true"} and work,but now cant send userid

Comment: if you mean send TOKEN for getting the current user ... you have to SEND IT VIA HEADERS .. WITH AUTHORIZATION : Bearer + YOURTOKEN

Comment: i mean in my web API i get a model and string, how to send that string?
try to send with header but not working

Comment: mmm try to send the string in the url .. something like localhost:3000/api/Users/YOURSTRING .. then in your webapi method you do something like  public void Put([FromUri] string id, [FromBody] Model model)  ... and use on your put method a decoration routing like this [Route("api/Users/{id}")]